# Changing the way automatic screen rotation works in Gnome shell

Tags: gnome3, udev, xrandr, touch-screen

I recently acquired a Lenovo Yoga 3 11" convertible notebook. It works well with out-of-the-box with Ubuntu Gnome LTS 16.04.2 - WiFi, Bluetooth, even suspend and resume work without any issues so far.

I noticed that Gnome 3 even allows the screen to auto-rotate based on the built-in rotation sensors. The Yoga 3 11" does offer rotation sensors via `iio-sensor-proxy` which is already installed by default in Ubuntu Gnome. As it happens, the orientation reported by `iio-sensor-proxy` seems to be off by 90°.

[Auto rotate screen on Dell 13 7000 with 15.04 (Gnome)](https://askubuntu.com/q/634151) has a solution in terms of a custom shell script which handles the screen rotation. I would rather not use this solution as it disables the "disable screen rotation" button in Gnome Shell.

I did some research already and found that `iio-sensor-proxy` should cause `udev` to trigger an event which is then used by Gnome 3 to set the screen orientation via `xrandr`. I cannot, however, find a way to tell either `udev` or Gnome 3 that the accelerometer is mounted in an orientation different from the display, which requires the directions to be translated in between.

So, the question is: How can that be done? The orientation remapping should be possible in either `iio-sensor-proxy`, `udev` or Gnome 3, and I actually don't care that much where it is done. I don't seem to find any config files I can easily change to achieve what I need.

As a workaround for now I am using the script from the Ask ubuntu question linked above, with modifications to account for the misaligned display/accelerometer issue. For this to work, I have to disable the automatic screen rotation in Gnome 3. Although this solution also allows automatically starting and killing `onboard` (on-screen keyboard) depending on current orientation, it kind of defeats the purpose of the Gnome 3 screen rotation setting.

Comment: https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy/issues/57

Answer (score 4):

See the answer by Krzysztof Stasiak for the theory.

In practice, my machine - a one mix one netbook 2s - by default has a screen rotated 90deg anticlockwise.

From what I understand, by default - every machine that doesn't have overrides has a matrix of ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1

Putting the following into /etc/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb fixed my case:

```
sensor:modalias:*
  ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=0, 1, 0; 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1
```

Comment: in my case I ONLY had to add my machine in the `/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-sensor.hwdb` file with the right formatting. the following was also helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410826/change-iio-sensors-data-via-custom-accel-mount-matrix

Answer (score 2):

From [GitLab iio-sensor-proxy site](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy/#accelerometer-orientation)
When the accelerometer is not mounted the same way as the screen, we need to modify the readings from the accelerometer to make sure that the computed orientation matches the screen one.

`iio-sensor-proxy` reads this information from the device's `ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX` udev property. See `60-sensor.hwdb` for details.