# ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX for ARCHOS 90 CESIUM

Tags: debian, gnome, tablet

I'm trying to install Debian 9 on an ARCHOS 90 CESIUM tablet. The basic stuff is already working with Liquorix kernel but with the accelerator (nor the touchscreen).

For the accelerator I'm following the instructions from [Change iio-sensors data via custom ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410826/change-iio-sensors-data-via-custom-accel-mount-matrix), but after several tries, I'm not able to put it working properly.

```
$ udevadm info -n "/dev/iio:device0"
P: /devices/platform/80860F41:02/i2c-2/i2c-SMO8500:00/iio:device0
N: iio:device0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/iio:device0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/80860F41:02/i2c-2/i2c-SMO8500:00/iio:device0
E: DEVTYPE=iio_device
E: IIO_SENSOR_PROXY_TYPE=iio-buffer-accel
E: MAJOR=245
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=iio
E: SYSTEMD_WANTS=iio-sensor-proxy.service
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=5497035

$ cat /sys/class/dmi/id/modalias 
dmi:bvnAmericanMegatrendsInc.:bvr5.6.5:bd07/18/2015:svnARCHOS:pnARCHOS90CESIUM:pvrTobefilledbyO.E.M.:rvnARCHOS:rnARCHOS90CESIUM:rvr1.0:cvnToBeFilledByO.E.M.:ct3:cvrToBeFilledByO.E.M.:

$ journalctl -b | grep iio
Jan 06 21:30:19 tablet iio-sensor-prox[416]: Could not find trigger name associated with /sys/devices/platform/80860F41:02/i2c-2/i2c-SMO8500:00/iio:device0
```

So, I created a custom sensor file for udev:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-sensor-local.hwdb
sensor:modalias:acpi:SMO8500:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnARCHOS:pnARCHOS90CESIUM:*
    ACCEL_MOUNT_MATRIX=0, 1, 0; -1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1
```

Updated udev hwdb and trigger...

```
$ systemd-hwdb update
$ udevadm trigger
```

...but the custom matrix does not appear...

```
$ udevadm info -export-db | grep ACCEL
$
```

I tried several formats, but no one works.

Comment: check also this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361472/changing-the-way-automatic-screen-rotation-works-in-gnome-shell/370155

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
sensor:modalias:acpi:SMO8500*:dmi:*:svnARCHOS*:pnARCHOS90CESIUM:*
```

as your udev-rule?

Did you do the hwdb-update as root / sudo?

Comment: I can't at this moment, but I'll give you feedback tomorrow. Thanks. Edited: all instructions above were executed as root :)

Comment: I tried that rule and still no luck :-\ Thanks anyway!